# Alternative of @RabbitListner annotation in Reactor RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want to use Reactor RabbitMQ for my existing RabbitMQ project with Spring boot(https://github.com/gotidhavalh/amqpdemo).

So I want to know how can I implement it and when any AMQP message is sent to any queue then how can I receive that AMQP message just like with @RabbitListner annotation in without Reactor case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no support for `@RabbitListener` with the reactive client.